# Why the peripheral devices won't completely power off

Tags: power-management

I'm working on a project that requires efficient power management, specifically the ability to shut off power to some peripheral circuits to save energy. My setup involves using a [TPS65261](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps65261.pdf?ts=1709599752260&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS65261) triple synchronous step-down converter to generate 3.3V, 1.8V, and 5V, which are delivered to various peripheral circuits. Managing the power of these outputs is crucial for the power-saving features of my project.

The TPS65261 has Enable pins designed to control the on/off state of its three buck converters, and I'm controlling these pins using an STM32F4 microcontroller. The STM32F4 is powered by a separate converter that is always on, ensuring that the microcontroller can manage the power states of the peripheral circuits at all times. This converter and the input supply of the TPS65261 are connected to my main power rail of 9V.

Here's the issue: while I can successfully control the on/off states of the 1.8V and 5V outputs, the 3.3V output does not fully shut off when its corresponding buck converter is disabled. Instead of dropping to 0V, it falls to about 1.47V and continues to consume power, which does not meet my power-saving requirements.

My questions are:

1. Are there any recommended troubleshooting steps or modifications to the circuit that could help resolve this issue?
2. Alternatively, if there's a better method for turning off peripheral circuits while minimizing power consumption, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: question #2 is not a question

Comment: question  #1 ... possibly ... depends on the circuit

Comment: Does the 3.3v rail fall all the way to zero if you turn all outputs off? Are there any interfaces crossing between the always-on supervisor rail and the 3.3v rail? (or any other external power, e.g: UARTs, I2C, etc...) If yes, what happens if you set those pins to Hi-Z?

Comment: Are there any active devices with their own power plugged into your project when you try to power down? A PC for example?

Comment: Is power coming out of the converter when the rail is switched off, or is one of the other devices on the rail back-driving it? Are you aware that many devices will draw power through I/O pins, if they are outside the range of GND-VCC, and back-drive their power pins? If not, now you are. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Are there any recommended troubleshooting steps or modifications to the circuit that could help resolve this issue?

Yes. The power is back-fed into the 3.3V circuit through signal/control lines. I mean: it has to come from **somewhere**. It is not the synchronous buck converter that is passing it. When the converter is off, there's no connection between the input and output sides. There would be a connection in a non-synchronous converter. If the converter is functional it's sensible to assume that it will properly turn all power switches off when you shut it down.

Although you should definitely verify that: disconnect the 3.3V buck output from the rest of the circuit to check if it's a "leaky" converter or is the load itself back-fed from somewhere. You have put some 0-ohm resistors in your prototype layout between the regulator outputs and the loads to isolate faults, I hope? If not, it's trace cutting time, and you hopefully won't forget the next time :)

> 2. Alternatively, if there's a better method for turning off peripheral circuits while minimizing power consumption, I'm open to suggestions.

Don't feed those circuits from anything, including control and signal lines. There's no magic happening here. Something is driving enough current into the 3.3V loads that they are "half-energized".

Recall that all CMOS chips have protection diodes that (among others) go from each pin to the most positive supply rail. The exception is special pins that allow higher input voltages. Those pins use isolation structures that still break down once the maximum voltage is exceeded. That's done to protect the I/O structures against ESD.

If *anything* is driving 3.3V logic signal into the 3.3V loads, there will be one diode drop less present on the VCC, back-driven from the signal line. Since the signal line usually is not strong enough, you may observe a lower voltage on VCC.

> the 3.3V output does not fully shut off when its corresponding buck converter is disabled

Based on what you told us (and you should tell us everything relevant, BTW), you absolutely don't know that. All you know is that the power is flowing from somewhere into the 3.3V loads. You have not measured anything that tells you it's flowing through the buck converter. The buck converter is not the only source of power to those 3.3V loads. Every single signal and control line going to 3.3V loads can power them.

---

Perhaps [the most famous case of this effect was during testing of the very first ARM chips](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2022/09/a-history-of-arm-part-1-building-the-first-chip/4/). But any time you're using CMOS chips, it'll be a potential source of trouble, and it can be insiduous.

> In fact, one of the first test boards the team plugged the ARM into had a broken connection and was not attached to any power at all. It was a big surprise when they found the fault because the CPU had been working the whole time. It had turned on just from electrical leakage coming [through the signal lines] from the support chips.

> The incredibly low power draw of the ARM chip was a “complete accident,” according to Wilson, but it would become important later.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful. One 3.3V load communicates with the MCU through SPI. The 3.3V buck converter is back-fed from the SPI line. That's why I still observe a lower voltage even when the buck converter is turned off. When I set all SPI pins to LOW before switching off the buck converter, I noticed a significant drop in total current consumption. However, when I check the output of the 3.3V buck converter, I still see around 0.4V. Are there any methods to solve this issue, such as adjusting the SPI GPIO mode?